# Google Maps: display an encoded polyline

Tags: google-maps

OK, so I have a polygon that is represented as an encoded polyline. I'd like to put this on a map, but can't figure out the syntax. Here's what I got:

```
  setRegion = new google.maps.Polyline({
    locations: "}~kvHmzrr@ba\hnc@jiu@r{Zqx~@hjp@pwEhnc@zhu@zflAbxn@fhjBvqHroaAgcnAp}gAeahAtqGkngAinc@_h|@r{Zad\y|_D}_y@swg@ysg@}llBpoZqa{@xrw@~eBaaX}{uAero@uqGadY}nr@`dYs_NquNgbjAf{l@|yh@bfc@}nr@z}q@i|i@zgz@r{ZhjFr}gApob@ff}@laIsen@dgYhdPvbIren@",
    levels: "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB",
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  setRegion.setMap(map);
```

Which I created using the [Polyline Encoder Tool](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility.html). From this same page I got its use, which is:

> The polyline encoding will appear in
>   the Encoded Polyline and Encoded
>   Levels fields below. Use these values
>   for **locations** and **levels** when you
>   create your google.maps.Polyline

However, the polygon does not appear. Anybody any idea what is going wrong?

UPDATE

I tried this, but get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'encoding' of undefined`.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Test</title> 
<meta charset="iso-8859-1"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>

<style type="text/css"> 
#map {width:670px;height:600px;}
</style> 
<script type='text/javascript'>
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.65905179951626, 7.3835928124999555);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath("}~kvHmzrr@ba\hnc@jiu@r{Zqx~@hjp@pwEhnc@zhu@zflAbxn@fhjBvqHroaAgcnAp}gAeahAtqGkngAinc@_h|@r{Zad\y|_D}_y@swg@ysg@}llBpoZqa{@xrw@~eBaaX}{uAero@uqGadY}nr@`dYs_NquNgbjAf{l@|yh@bfc@}nr@z}q@i|i@zgz@r{ZhjFr}gApob@ff}@laIsen@dgYhdPvbIren@");
    var decodedLevels = decodeLevels("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");

    setRegion = new google.maps.Polyline({
        locations: decodedPath,
        levels: decodedLevels,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
    setRegion.setMap(map);

}

function decodeLevels(encodedLevelsString) {
    var decodedLevels = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < encodedLevelsString.length; ++i) {
        var level = encodedLevelsString.charCodeAt(i) - 63;
        decodedLevels.push(level);
    }
    return decodedLevels;
}


</script> 
</head> 


<body onload="initialize()"> 

<div id="map"></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedPath:string)

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#encoding

From that page:

```
var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedPolyline);
var decodedLevels = decodeLevels(encodedLevels);

// Decode an encoded levels string into an array of levels.
function decodeLevels(encodedLevelsString) {
  var decodedLevels = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < encodedLevelsString.length; ++i) {
    var level = encodedLevelsString.charCodeAt(i) - 63;
    decodedLevels.push(level);
  }

  return decodedLevels;
}
```

Make sure the geometry libaray is being loaded per: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Libraries

Working example of the encoded polyline at: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanrolds/ukRsp/

Comment: I tried doing this, but it does not work (see updated question).

Comment: The geometry library being loaded? What does the Google maps include look like?

Comment: The Geometry Library was indeed not loaded. However, after loading the polyline shape still does not show up. Full HTML code included in the original question.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanrolds/ukRsp/

The polyline is showing fine in that example. 

Something to note: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm.html

- "Note that the backslash is interpreted as an escape character within string literals. Any output of this utility should convert backslash characters to double-backslashes within string literals."

Comment: Thanks! I changed the backslashes AND the way setRegion is defined, and it now works! Excellent!

Comment: I know this is old but I've been looking around and I can't find a definition of what 'levels' refers to in your encoded/decoded levels? It seems to be set automatically to level 3 (as a 'B'). What are the other options and what does it change?

Comment: Pretty sure it's zoom level. It's been a while. Review: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm?hl=en and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility

Answer (score 16):

If you're getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'encoding' of undefined
```

Then the Geometry library is not being loaded. Add the geometry library (&libraries=geometry) to the google maps api load like in:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but if you store your encoded polylines and/or levels in variables (like elements of an array of polylines), String() function is required:

```
polyLayer = [
[['ynh`IcftoCyq@Ne@ncBds@EEycB'],
 ['PHIHP']],
...
];

...
for (var i = 0; i < polyLayer.length; i++) {
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        ...,
        path: google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(String(polyLayer[i][0])), 
        levels: decodeLevels(String(polyLayer[i][1])), 
        ...
    }); 
    poly.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have locations:, not path: in your options! I noticed this as the generator tool states to use locations, but I think that is incorrect, not sure as I am new to this also! It seems to work with path.